# ffmpeg / video processing: make video repeat itself without duplicating content?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, compression, video-editing

Suppose I have a video file that is 20 MB in size and lasts 30 seconds.

I want to create a new video file that basically consists of the existing video, repeated 10 times. So the new video should last 300 seconds (5 minutes) and contain the same content every 30 seconds.

I could of course append this video to itself 10 times, resulting in a file of approximately 200 MB. But this seems very redundant, since obviously the same content is in there tenfold. I was hoping for a somewhat more intelligent approach, where the same 30 seconds of video is somehow 'referenced' 10 times over.

Do common encoders or container formats (say h.264 in a .mp4 or .mkv container) support this? And by any chance is there a way to pull this off with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to create an [M3U playlist file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) (`playlist.m3u8`) that repeats the same file 10 times.

Example:

Create 30 seconds synthetic video (for testing):

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=30 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=inputs=2" -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 44100 -t 30 input.mp4
```

Assume `input.mp4` is your 30 seconds video.

---

Re-mux the MP4 file to TS container format (the playlist is not going to work with MP4 file):

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -codec copy input.ts
```

---

Create a text file named `playlist.m3u8` with the following content:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXTINF:30.00,
input.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

You can play `playlist.m3u8` file with most video players.

---

In most cases the input file is splinted into small segments (used for Web video streaming):

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -codec copy -f segment input%3d.ts
```

Creating playlist of segments:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:30.00,
input000.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input001.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input002.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input003.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input000.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input001.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input002.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,
input003.ts
#EXTINF:30.00,

...

#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

---

The playlist solution is the only solution I can think of.
The format is mostly used for HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) format.
It is not the same as having a single video file (in terms of seeking for example).

As far as I know it is not possible using classic video containers like MP4 or MKV.

There is also an option to play the same file 10 times (probably not relevant), for example:

```
ffplay -loop 10 input.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But the context I had in mind was to be able to upload a video file created like this. Unfortunately in most cases I won't be able to upload a .m3u8 along with one or more .mp4 or .ts files as one single video. But this is already helpful, much appreciated 